# Internal Testing app on Google Play only gives uninstall option, can't open

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-internal-testing

I've released an app to some internal testers on the Google Play Store but although they can install the app, they only see the "Uninstall" option on the app's info screen, no option to run it. They're logged into the right Google account to be able to download and test the app..
What do I need to do to be able to run the app, or what do I need to change as a developer (it's a Flutter app) to allow it to be run?

[image: Example where there's no "Open" option]

I've turned off Play Protect and 2-Step Verification in my Google account and allowed "less secure apps" but that hasn't helped.

Cheers

Comment: how did you get past this?